Use debs from the ubutu pro subscription to the unsubscribed machine
I want to check is it going to be licensing breach if I copy the deb files which are from the Ubuntu pro licensed machine and install it on another machine where license is not activated.
I want to minimize the network utilization in my home lab by hosting the deb file locally.

This was covered in the discussion thread of the Ubuntu Pro FAQ:

Is it permitted to redistribute Ubuntu Pro packages, including those packages that are not licensed under GPL? (I don’t think you could restrict the right to redistribute GPL packages without violating GPL.)
— ethanc8, Oct. 16, 2024


hi @ethanc8 ! thanks for reaching out!
Ubuntu Pro subscriptions include access to many different kinds of software, ranging from kernel patches to proprietary applications. Some of these are licensed under open source licenses, while others are not.
Section 4 of the Ubuntu Pro service terms covers licensing. Specifically, section 4.4 applies to software under the subscription that is not licensed under an open source license. That section grants a license to the Ubuntu Pro subscriber to use the software, but not to redistribute it.
— Lech, Oct. 18, 2024

So check the licenses of the packages you want to copy. If they're under a free or open source license like GPL, BSL, etc., then sure, you can copy them to other systems. If they're under a restrictive license, then, see the aforementioned section 4.4:

To the extent any Software provided to Customer is not under an open source licence, Canonical grants to Customer a world-wide, non-exclusive, non-transferable licence for the term of the applicable Order, revocable in the event of breach or termination of this Agreement or the applicable Order, to (i) use the Licensed IP in accordance with this Agreement, solely in connection with systems which are the subject of the Order, and subject to any quantity, usage or other limitations or restrictions set out in the applicable Order and (ii) to make a reasonable number of copies of the Licensed IP for backup and installation purposes. Customer may not use, copy, modify, disassemble, decompile, reverse engineer, or distribute the Licensed IP except as expressly permitted in this Agreement or an Order, or permit access to the Licensed IP to any third party other than those acting on Customer’s behalf except as expressly permitted in this Agreement or an Order. Nothing in this Agreement limits rights under any individual open source licence for the source code of packages in the Software.

From "solely in connection with systems which are the subject of the Order", I'd say such packages can't be copied to systems not under a subscription.
